# jQuery Datatables and Google Charts API

Tags: jquery, mysql, google-visualization

I have a situation where I am using jQuery datatables to display some data, and using their built in filtering, the data is filtered down based on select box options as the user changes them.

I need the user to be able to click a button and generate a Google Column Chart based on the current data filtered in the datatable. I can't wrap my head around how to get the current data in the table to the chart data variable.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There is a plugin that someone made to get filtered results from the datatables. I then got the data i needed in jquery, did the math and created the 2D array that google charts needed :)

https://code.google.com/p/sail-web/source/browse/trunk/vlewrapper/WebContent/vle/jquery/jquery-dataTables/js/dataTables.fnGetFilteredNodes.js?r=2311